# Moped::Errors::ConnectionFailure: Could not connect to any secondary or primary nodes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, mongoid, moped

I have been trying to configure MongoDB (Mongoid) to work in my Rails application but I am helpless as I have tried pretty much everything I could find online yet I am getting this error message everytime there is a database line in my code. The repo for my app is [here](https://github.com/sebkomianos/hnfox) and the full message is this:

```
Moped::Errors::ConnectionFailure: Could not connect to any secondary or primary nodes for replica set <Moped::Cluster nodes=[<Moped::Node resolved_address="127.0.0.1:3000">]>
```

**Update:** Ran rs.status() on mongo shell, as per @BrandonBlack's suggestion, and got this:

`{ "ok" : 0, "errmsg" : "not running with --replSet" }`

Comment: Can you use the mongo shell and run rs.status() on your database and post the results?

Comment: @BrandonBlack Updated the question. I am assuming I need to set up some kind of replica set and configure my hosts as well? Any leads on how to to this without messing anything?

Comment: Have you actually setup your MongoDB as replica set??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seemed to be that I had misconfigured the port for the databases in mongoid.yml, as it should **only** be 27017. I hope I don't need to revisit this question with another problem. :)